# Proyecto Java EE, Netbeans + GlassFish pasarlo a tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish

Mi pregunta es básicamente si se tiene un proyecto en Java desarrollado desde 0 con Netbeans + GlassFish, ¿Hay que realizar alguna configuración para continuar el desarrollo con un tomcat?

Comment: En un principio no. EN Netbeans (o cualquier IDE) tu lo que haces es crear código y al final debes exportar un war que vas a desplegar en un contenedor. A partir de ahí todo es cuestión de configuración del propio servidor. No sé en que difieren glassfish y tomcat pero no debe haber mucha diferencia.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la rta